# Update data programmatically in code(Java) or in database using trigger (MySQL)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Edit : I need the program to do computational faster, the update process is needed to be real time (calculating 100.000 to 200.000 records for about 0-5 seconds), this process will be doing in multi threading (about 2-8 thread)

---

I will create program that will update data in database. The update process will be triggered if I do insert data in table. The update process will computational costly. This is the idea of my update process :

1. I will have 3 tables (A,B,C) and each of it will have data aroud 100.000-200.000 records
2. I will have table D to save table A, B, C record count
3. I will have table E to save table A, B, C, D calculation, the calculation including multiplication, division and log base 2
4. I will insert data to table A, B, C and after that data in table D and E must be updated
5. This process can be repeated 3-5 times in every update

Which one is computationally faster, doing update programmatically or using trigger?

Answer (score 3):

Better to go with `TRIGGERS` and keep this complexity on DB side. This will help you in keeping your code clean. If you are going to do `INSERT` from different files then you may need to rewrite `UPDATE` logic in all those files.

And if in future you need to change the after insert logic then you just need to update your trigger instead of updating the code.

Comment: +1 for keeping the data logic in the database where it belongs instead of putting it in application code like so many people make the mistake of doing.

Answer (score 1):

Computational cycles in your database server are a scarce resource. You can have as many server instances running your Java program as you can afford, and as your application scales up (adds users, for example) you can distribute the computationally intensive operation to multiple servers.

If you perform the computationally expensive stuff on your MySQL server, you are deciding to do it all on a central machine.

Plus, in my experience, it is easier to unit test and maintain Java code than it is to do the same for trigger / stored procedure code.

That being said, MySQL's floating-point math operations (log, multiplication) exploit the server's math instruction set and are reasonably efficient.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your answer. If it's data logic, it's better to put it in the database. Database servers can scale as well (e.g. clustering) as app servers, so I don't really understand your argument. When you put the data logic in the database, then no matter which application has to access that data, the logic is in a centralized place. If you put in in your Java code, what happens next year when somebody want's to write a .Net app to access the DB? They have to duplicate that data logic, or use your Java code "middle tier" somehow. Here's a good link: http://goo.gl/c2TfUL

Comment: As far as "easier to maintain", it depends on the familiarity with a given language. If you're a Java programmer, then your argument is true. If you're a stored procedure MySQL coder, then your argument may not be true. Code is code, you can write bad code in any language, or good code. You can also unit test stored procedures. That doesn't mean Java is "better" than a database language like PL/SQL or MySQL's SQL dialect.

Comment: @dcp could you enlighten me a bit on unit testing stored procedures? We have a big and complex DB2 installation with lots of stored procedures, cross-referencing other schemas, MQ queues etc. We have no idea how those would be unit testable. Can you give an example how this would be done?

Comment: also, we are planning to migrate data handling out of the database, because we have to pay for database server cycles on the mainframe a *lot* more than we pay for counting on the app servers. Based on that alone I would agree on computational cycles on a database server as being a scarce resource, as in practice we've seen we cannot afford them.

Comment: For Oracle, for example, there's utPLSQL (http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/). I've used it many times and it works great. You use it just like any other testing framework (it has assertions to validate expected results, etc.) I can't speak for DB2 unit testing frameworks, but it looks like they exist: http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2unit/

Comment: As for mainframe expenses, why not just consider moving to a cheaper database platform (Linux comes to mind) rather than migrating data logic out of the database into Java code? My feeling is, data logic belongs with data. Then all the applications can take advantage of that by not having to duplicate the data logic over and over again (and probably make mistakes in the process).

Comment: @dcp that db2unit link is just to an empty shell project, zero files. There are some frameworks that can be used to some extent, but I haven't seen any that would allow testing db2 stored procedures.

Comment: and yes, we're moving lot of the stuff to Linux platform on lower environments. However, mainframe is the platform of choice for us in production, so that's what we need to live with. I'm not saying that this situation applies to everybody, but it certainly applies to us - sometimes database resources are too expensive to be used very extensively.

Comment: @eis - Understood, everyone's situation can definitely vary. Thanks for the good discussion.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger will be faster as it will work closest to the data and you will not have to transfer data between the database and the program layer. The problem with a trigger is that it will be triggered for every insert. Is that something that you want or would you prefer to only do the computation once a lot of data (ie many inserts) has been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

> I will have 3 tables (A,B,C) and each of it will have data aroud
>   100.000-200.000 records

This is a trivially small database.

```
I will have table D to save table A, B, C record count
```

Are you keeping a history of records in each on a particular datetime?  That's the only reason to do this.

```
I will have table E to save table A, B, C, D calculation, the calculation including multiplication, division and log base 2
```

Easy stuff.

```
I will insert data to table A, B, C and after that data in table D and E must be updated
```

Making all of this a single unit of work is the important thing.  I hope you're making them a transaction.

This process can be repeated 3-5 times in every update Which one is faster, doing update programmatically or using trigger?

I would think database - stored procedure and trigger first.  Especially if there are a lot of UPDATEs.

Are the three sources of data A, B, and C independent?  If I INSERT into A, do I execute the calculations for D and E?  Likewise for B and C?  Could you potentially have a great deal of traffic if all three have records INSERTed in a short period of time?

Comment: data A, B and C are independent

Comment: What is the total rate of data insert into all three?  One row per second?  Ten?  Thousands?

Comment: about 1-5 rows per second, but the computational process very expensive, to insert one row data we need to do about 10-30 seconds computational process

Comment: Can't work, can it?  30 seconds?  I don't believe it, not on the basis of what you've posted.  I'd rewrite the calculation in such a way that the new value is calculated from the old value plus some increment by the new value rather than having to rescan the entire table.

Comment: because I need to calculate before insert and doing it with multi-thread, I think MySQL cannot handle the traffic

Comment: I think that if your calculation takes 30 seconds, and you have to do it once every 1-5 seconds, that the problem isn't MySQL.  You'll have to think about this problem differently to get it done.   Algorithm change, schema change, indexes - you're the problem, not the database.